# Correct usage of HTML5 <address> element?

Tags: html

I'm searching for correct usage of `<address>` element.

For example, i have to show more than one address, so i need to write them in an address element or seperate for each other?

```
<p>BLA BLA CO.</p>
<address>
    <span class="full-address">XXX ST. XXX ETC.</span>
    <span class="city">IZMIR</span>
    <span class="town">Bornova</span>
    <span class="phone">+11 111 111 1111</span>
    <span class="fax">+11 111 111 1112</span>
</address>

<p>OTHER BLA CO.</p>
<address>
    <span class="full-address">XXX ST. XXX ETC.</span>
    <span class="city">IZMIR</span>
    <span class="town">Bornova</span>
    <span class="phone">+11 111 111 1111</span>
    <span class="fax">+11 111 111 1112</span>
</address>
```

What is the correct usage of this?

Comment: http://html5doctor.com/the-address-element/ read this :)

Comment: I did. But it is not really explaining to use multiple addresses. As i said, i did search for a couple site but nothing really helped. So, i'm here to get opinions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your use-case, it probably is incorrect usage.

As per the official refs:

> The address element must not be used to represent arbitrary addresses
>   (e.g. postal addresses), unless those addresses are in fact the
>   relevant contact information. (The p element is the appropriate
>   element for marking up postal addresses in general.)

<sub>Ref, Living standard: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#the-address-element</sub>

<sub>Ref, Spec HTML4.01: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.6</sub>

<sub>Ref, Recomendation HTML5: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-address-element</sub>

.

You are presenting several postal addresses, and so it seems a `p` is more appropriate here. Regarding `address`, it represents contact information for its nearest `article` or `body` and is also allowed in `footer`.

Comment: HTML5 is now a Recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

Well, depending on this [source](http://www.html5-tutorials.org/new-section-tags/address-tag/) the `<address>` tag is not an actually address in your usecase. Its more like a pointer to the page author. Means, it should contain your own address.

Additional info by [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_address.asp)

- The `<address>` tag defines the contact information for the author/owner of a document or an article.
- If the `<address>` element is inside the `<body>` element, it represents contact information for the document.
- If the `<address>` element is inside an `<article>` element, it represents contact information for that article.

Comment: Please use references that are not w3schools; it often contains inaccuracies. [The MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/address)  and [the HTML5 recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-address-element) on w3.org are excellent references.

Comment: Will look after it in the future. In this case i didn´t want to quote something without a source and the conclusion from w3schools was pretty accurate at this point.